# Can someone give me a reference to enable /actuator/jolokia on a Spring Boot application version 3.1.5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, jolokia

I want to enable jolokia on Spring Boot application but seems I am not able to do that with jolokia-core dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jolokia/jolokia-core.
I was able to do that with 2.x.x releases of Spring Boot. Any changes required to enable this endpoint?

Enabled jolokia on 2.x.x

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your class path:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
    <artifactId>jolokia-support-spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for Jolokia was dropped from Spring Boot since Jolokia didn't support Servlet API 5.0 yet ([see issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28704)). Jolokia will add support for the new Servlet API with release 2.0 ([see issue](https://github.com/jolokia/jolokia/issues/568)).

So to answer your question: it's currently not possible to enable the `/actuator/jolokia` endpoint within Spring Boot 3.x. You'll have to wait until Jolokia releases v2.0, and then for a new Spring Boot version that will re-enable support.